# Get auto-increment id after an insert query using mysqli_multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is the problem I need to do multiple insert into multiple tables, using mysqli_multi_query, when the  id of the first insert need to be inserted into the second tables as FK, I know how to do this if they use two different connections, but how it can be done when they both are in a same query since imce using mysqli_multi_query?

%% by the way i use MySQLi along with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` with your second insert statement

Comment: You mean my query should be something like this: insert into first_table(id, name) values ('id','name');  insert into second_table (id,name) values (select last_insert_id(),name);   ?